# Resizing cell height dynamically Android

Tags: android, listview, dynamic, cell

I have a ListView. In the XML it looks like this:

Relative Layout height = 250

[image: Relative Layout height = 250]

and

Relative Layout Height = 120

[image]

Now, by default, the height is 120. I have an `OnClickListener` for the expandable icon in the top right corner. This is the code:

```
        expand.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                expanded = true;
            }
        });
```

and

```
if(expanded){
    rcell.getLayoutParams().height = 250;
}else{
    rcell.getLayoutParams().height = 120;
```

Unfortunately the boolean value `expanded` seems to be staying the same throughout all the objects.

Because of this when I click the `expand` button, after scrolling down, all cells expand.

How do I approach this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm just making a wild assumption that your code is in the getView function of an adapter.

If that's the case, it seems like your boolean "expanded" is a private member of that adapter. This means that clicking your expanded button will set it to true, and when the listview redraws it will be true for all rows.

In my opinion your solutions are either look at ExpandableListView or alter your code to keep track of which rows in your listview should be expanded, something like below.

```
// List that keep track of expanded states for each row.
private ArrayList<boolean> rowExpandedStates = new ArrayList<>();

public MyAdapterConstructor()
{
    // Default false state for all rows.
    // Insert false on as many rows that this list should have
    for (int i = 0; i < totalRows; i++)
        rowExpandedStates.add(false);

}


// And the following code below in your getView function of the adapter.

expand.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // Should this row be expanded or not?
        // The getView function has a parameter which gives you the current row
        rowExpandedStates.set(rowIndex, !rowExpandedStates.get(rowIndex));
    }
});

// Check if the current row should be expanded when the row is drawn
if(rowExpandedStates.get(rowIndex)){
    rcell.getLayoutParams().height = 250;
}else{
    rcell.getLayoutParams().height = 120;
```

Comment: Yes, I'll give this a shot. How come, the views are different in all cells (specific to each one), but the boolean value is constant throughout all the cells?

Comment: That is just a matter of coding. It would be easier to answer this question if  you could post your entire getView function of your adapter. getView returns a View for each row. Your boolean belongs to your adapter which means that you at first had one boolean for all rows instead of one for each row.